# How to determine component type

Tags: java, components, jdialog

I am processing a number of JDialog components looking for a specific type with a specific client property. I understand how to check a clientproperty but I cannot find a method that returns the component type as a string. I want to do something like this:

```
Component[] fields = timeLineDialog.getContentPane().getComponents();
for (Component field : fields) {
    if (field.<getType>.equals("JComboBox") {
        .
        .
        .
}
```

I can get the components but I can't figure out how to determine the type. What method(s) can I use for ? TIA.

Comment: getClass().getName() returns the runtime classname. But java recommends to use  the instanceof instruction.

Comment: Your request sounds like you have a design problem. Read about MVC/MVVC pattern, then change your code so that you can work with *Listeners* on that Input components changing the model instead of having a god like class doing all that.

Comment: I take a look at that but I'm not sure how that will help me find a specific component when I need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `instanceof` operator.

```
for (Component field : fields) {
    if (field instanceof JComboBox) {
        // do something
    } else if (field instanceof JButton) {
        // do something
    } else if (field instanceof JPanel) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

See: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0060__Operators/TheinstanceofKeyword.htm

Comment: There does not seem to be a getClass method for 'Components'. I guess I would need to use a switch-case statement to process every possible component type to find the one I want if I use instance of. Can a switch-case do that?

Comment: You can go with nested `if`s. But consider the hint of @TimothyTruckle and re-think the design of your code. Should you really test the class of components? Maybe another approach could be more suitable.

Comment: I'm not sure why but my IDE (Eclipse) did not originally present the Class() method for 'field'. When I quit and later restarted my development, it suddenly showed up as did the getNameByType() method. I needed that for debugging purposes but I did change my methodology and am using instanceof. Thanks.